# Terraform workspace specific lines of code

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Im having an issue using terraform workspaces between a region pair.  One workspace for South Central US and one for North Central US.  Everything works great until it comes to zones. Public IP for example. South I’m setting zones, North won’t accept zone configuration empty, 0, or 1,2, or 3 because it doesn’t support zones yet. Hoping to set zones in SCU and eventually doing the same in NCU when they become available.

How do I use the same code in both regions?  I know I can use workspace vars for values, but in this case it is an entire line of code. Seems like there should be an easy answer I’m just not thinking of.

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: It’s a general question.  A “line of code” in one workspace, no “line of code” in a different workspace.  Don’t get caught up in the code.  

But if it helps it’s the zones line.  
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/public_ip#zones

Zones are supported in one region, not in another.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question differently and got the answer I was looking for.  Instead of trying to put a value in the zones config line, just put null.  TF omits that line and sends it.  Simple and it worked.

Here's an example of my variables.tfvars

```
firewalla-AvailabilityZone    = {
    hub-ncu        = null
    hub-scu        = [1]
}
firewallb-AvailabilityZone    = {
    hub-ncu        = null
    hub-scu        = [3]
}
```

Then in the resource:

```
zones = var.firewalla-AvailabilityZone[terraform.workspace]
```